# Creating Slugs from Titles?

Tags: javascript, regex, slug

I have everything in place to create slugs from titles, but there is one issue. My RegEx replaces spaces with hyphens. But when a user types "Hi     there" (multiple spaces) the slug ends up as "Hi-----there". When really it should be "Hi-there".

Should I create the regular expression so that it only replaces a space when there is a character either side?

Or is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: The problem is the titles are created on the fly, using Javascript, to show the user what his URL will look like. It's for a social network.

Comment: JavaScript is a programming language, and it can do regex. What's the problem?

Answer (score 16):

I use this:

```
yourslug.replace(/\W+/g, '-')
```

This replaces all occurrences of one or more non-alphanumeric characters with a single dash.

Comment: Note: this also matches underscores. If you want it to replace them as well just go `yourslug.replace(/[\W_]/g, '-')`

Answer (score 5):

Just match multiple whitespace characters.

```
s/\s+/-/g
```

Answer (score 3):

Daniel's answer is correct.

However if somebody is looking for complete solution I like this function,

http://dense13.com/blog/2009/05/03/converting-string-to-slug-javascript/

Thanks to "dense13"!

Comment: Great solution. Just change 'from' and 'to' vars to language you need.

Answer (score 2):

It might be the easiest to fold repeated `-`s into one `-` as the last step:

```
replace /-{2,}/ by "-"
```

Or if you only want this to affect spaces, fold spaces instead (before the other steps, obviously)

Answer (score 0):

I would replace `[\s]+` with `'-'` and *then* replace `[^\w-]` with `''`

Comment: You could add an additional `[\-]+` => `'-'` right at the end to replace multiple -s

Answer (score 0):

You may want to trim the string first, to avoid leading and trailing hyphens.

```
function hyphenSpace(s){
    s= (s.trim)? s.trim(): s.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'');
    return s.split(/\s+/).join('-');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily by using a simple package `@smflow/seo-slug` to generate slug from Title or any text: [Github](https://www.github.com/smflow/seo-slug)

## How to generate

### install the package: @smflow/seo-slug

`npm install @smflow/seo-slug`

### Generate the slug

```js
import { genSlug } from "@smflow/seo-slug";

const slug = genSlug("This is a blog title to generate slug");
console.log(slug); // this-is-a-blog-title-to-generate-slug1234
```