# Slugify an Acronym List with XSLT

Tags: regex, xslt, slug

Have a requirement to create slugs from XML content.

I was navigating to create Slugs from Titles and found the below ones listed.

- [Creating Slugs from Titles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2993119/creating-slugs-from-titles)
- [Java code/library for generating slugs (for use in pretty URLs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657193/java-code-library-for-generating-slugs-for-use-in-pretty-urls)
- and similar others.

I was looking for perfect solution for an XSL solution, which provides better slugifies like a PHP solution: http://blog.tersmitten.nl/slugify and also takes care of duplicates in the file system.

#### Input XML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>2D</td>
        <td>Two Dimension</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>A/C</td>
        <td>Account</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>A/C</td>
        <td>Air Condition</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>L&T</td>
        <td>Larsen & Toubro</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>M + [ # ]</td>
        <td>Modified Algo</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

#### Expected Output

```
file: 2d.txt
------------
2D
Two Dimension

file: a-c.txt
-------------
A/C
Account

file: a-c-2.txt
---------------
A/C
Air Condition

file: l-t.txt
-------------
L&T
Larsen & Turbo

file: m.txt (NOT m-.txt)
-------------
M + [ # ]
Modified Algo
```

#### Tried XSL

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<xsl:stylesheet extension-element-prefixes="redirect" version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:redirect="http://xml.apache.org/xalan/redirect">

    <xsl:output method="text" version="1.0" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="table/tr">
            <!-- The logic for variable value requires attention!! -->
            <xsl:variable name="acronym" select="translate(td[1], 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')" />
            <xsl:variable name="tmpFilename" select="concat('C:/Temp/', $acronym, '.txt')" />

            <xsl:variable name="filename">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="document($tmpFilename)">
                        <!-- Require logic to handle duplicate file existence. -->
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$filename" />
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:variable>

            <redirect:write select="$filename">
                <xsl:value-of select="td[1]" />
                <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="td[2]" />
            </redirect:write>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Note:** The file name should include only the OS supported characters. The rest should be converted to '-'. Also, there shouldn't be leading and trailing '-' characters (e.g. the last output file as mentioned above).

Comment: From where are you running this XSLT? Text handling (or file writing, for that matter) is not exactly the kind of thing XSLT was designed for, you might want to use something else.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a Java based solution, I have an [online generator](https://www.bonkersabouttech.com/tools/slug-generator) which you can use.  If you look in the Javascript, you'll find the POST request that you need to make - just don't hammer it please ;)